# App crashes during reading of row from table

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I'm getting an error while reading a row from table. My app works like this:

- in the main activity you select which table you want to display
- then another activity will start showing every single entry in the database
- and when you click on the item in list view, another activity will start loading the selected row columns in edit texts - and this is where the error happens.

  ```
  public class DVD_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
  String a;
  String b;
  DB_Worker dw;
  int x;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_dvd_activity);
      NapojAdapter();
      pridajListener();
  }

  private void NapojAdapter() {
      dw = new DB_Worker(this);
      SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.dvd_list_layout,dw.VratKurzorD(),new String[] { DVD.KEY_ID,
              DVD.KEY_title,DVD.KEY_autor},new int[] {R.id.id2, R.id.nazov, R.id.autor},0);

      ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
      lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dvd_activity, menu);
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      int id = item.getItemId();

      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
          return true;
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  public void button4click(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent (this, Pridaj_DVD.class);
      String verzia = "1";
      intent.putExtra("verzia",verzia);
      startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
  }

  private void pridajListener() {
      AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

          TextView lv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.id2);
          x = Integer.parseInt(lv.getText().toString());
          DVD s = dw.getDVD(x);
          a =s.title;
          b = s.autor;
          String verzia = "2";
          Intent intent = new Intent(DVD_activity.this,Pridaj_DVD.class);
          intent.putExtra("verzia", verzia);
          intent.putExtra("a",a);
          intent.putExtra("b",b);
          startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

      }};
      ListView myList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
      myList.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);

  }

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == 1) {
          if (resultCode == 0) {
              DVD s = new DVD();
              s.title = data.getStringExtra("a");
              s.autor = data.getStringExtra("b");
              dw.addDVD(s);
              NapojAdapter();
              }
          if (resultCode == 1) {
              dw.deleteDVD(x);
              NapojAdapter();
          }
          if (resultCode == 2) {
              a = data.getStringExtra("a");
              b = data.getStringExtra("b");
              dw.updateDVD(Integer.toString(x),a,b);
              NapojAdapter();
          }

      }
  }
  }
  ```

here is the `DB_WORKER` class:

```
public class DB_Worker {
public SQLiteDatabase db;
private DB_Helper dbHelper;

public DB_Worker(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new DB_Helper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void addDVD(DVD s) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DVD.KEY_title, s.title);
    values.put(DVD.KEY_autor, s.autor);

    long newRowId = db.insert(DVD.TABLE,null,values);
}   

public DVD getDVD(long ID) {
    DVD s = new DVD();

    VratKurzorD();
    String[] projection = {DVD.KEY_title, DVD.KEY_autor};
    String selection = DVD.KEY_ID;
    String[] selectionArgs = {""+ID};
    Cursor c = db.query(DVD.TABLE,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);

    s.DVD_ID = ID;
    s.title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DVD.KEY_title));
    s.autor = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DVD.KEY_autor));

    c.close();
    return s;
}   

public void updateDVD(String ID, String title, String autor)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DVD.KEY_title,title);
    cv.put(DVD.KEY_autor, autor);
    db.update(DVD.TABLE, cv, DVD.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[]{ID});
}

public void deleteDVD(int ID) {
    db.delete(DVD.TABLE, DVD.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[]{"" + ID});
}

public Cursor VratKurzorD() {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+DVD.TABLE, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}

}
```

and here is the error:

```
12-03 23:11:42.240 2067-2067/com.example.lowrider.pozicovna E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.lowrider.pozicovna, PID: 2067 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
        at com.example.lowrider.pozicovna.DB_Worker.getDVD(DB_Worker.java:78)
        at com.example.lowrider.pozicovna.DVD_activity$1.onItemClick(DVD_activity.java:66)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

Info from log: `Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.` indicates that in some place you've written query like:
`Select * from table` which doesn't require any argument but you that argument deliver.
So you should search query in your code which doesn't have any `?` but you pass argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

In method `getDVD(long ID)` change

```
String selection = DVD.KEY_ID;
```

to

```
String selection = DVD.KEY_ID + "=?";
```

**Update 1:**

Also, add a call to [moveToFirst()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) to position cursor to first row:

```
Cursor c = db.query(DVD.TABLE,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
c.moveToFirst();
```

This will work if the cursor contains at least one row. If it is possible for the cursor to be empty, you need to check the boolean status returned.

Comment: OK I've tried it and now it throws som other errors:

Process: com.example.lowrider.pozicovna, PID: 2195
    android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
            at com.example.lowrider.pozicovna.DB_Worker.getDVD(DB_Worker.java:81)...

Comment: Thank you the c.moveToFirst(); worked you are my hero !

Comment: @Lowrider Glad it help.  Please accept my answer so that others will know it solved the problem.